# Using python-requests to log in to a website and get HTML source of the next page

Tags: python, get, python-requests

I performed  `r = requests.get(url, auth=(login_id, password))`.

I was expecting to be directed to the next page, that comes after logging in, but when I checked `r.text`,

it contained the HTML text of the url page itself.

Also, I checked `r.cookies`, which contained the Session ID.

How do I go to the next page?

Comment: Are you sure that the site you are trying to access use HTTP Basic Auth? (The browser popup where you enter login/password)

Comment: How do I find that out?

Comment: Does it look like this when you try to log in: http://i.imgur.com/6rEG6Eq.png - If it does, it is HTTP Basic Auth, and you can use the auth keyword argument. If not, you must do as fredtantini has answered.

Comment: Nope it does not look like that.

http://pict.ethdigitalcampus.com/PICT/

Answer (score 0):

If it's a logging page as in facebook, twitter, etc. you have to simulate the click on the «submit/login» button on the form:

```
login_data = { 'login': login_id, 
               'password': password,
                'dbConnVar': 'PICT',
                'service_id': ''}

urlToVisit = 'http://www.example.com'

with session() as s:
    req = s.post(urlToVisit + '/login.php', data=login_data)
    req = s.get(url + '/my_account.php')
```

Comment: I am receiving Session Expired when I try to perform get().

This is the URL btw - http://pict.ethdigitalcampus.com/PICT/

Comment: Updated login_data from your url

Comment: Should I leave service_id blank?

Comment: It is when I look at the param of the POST request (F12 on firefox, Network Tab, params Tab)

Comment: I dont know why, but my Network Monitor in Firefox doesn't show anything at all. How can I find the Service ID in Chrome?

Comment: In chrome: F12, Network, go to your url, then enter login/pwd, then click on the post request (authenticate.do), choose Headers Tab, and look at Form Data.

Comment: Yup, found the form data. The response headers's location field is - http://pict.ethdigitalcampus.com/DCWeb/form/jsp_home/Index.jsp?portlet=home - which is the current URL. When I perform get() on that in the code, I get Session Expired.
Code - http://pastebin.com/wZrQAdzq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58610/discussion-between-fredtantini-and-rayu).